# how to navigate to a hash id within the same page in angular when <base href="/">

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

My Index.html is something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Page</title>
  <base href="/">
 ...
</head>
```

So All pages in the application have `<base href="/">`, due to which if I create an anchor tag with `href="#someID"`, The navigation works fine on homepage but on any other page it fails because of `<base href="/">` on all pages.
For Example:

this href ->`<a href="#someID">Go to some Id</a>`

works fine on my home page `localhost:4200`

but not on `localhost:4200/nextPage`

URL is always resolved relative to home, like localhost:4200/#someID instead of localhost:4200/nextPage#someID when I am on the nextPage.

Answer (score 0):

In your *app-routing.module.ts* you should declare a route in the *route* object as follows:

```
{ path: 'products/product/:productId', component: ProductItemPageComponent },
```

Then in your method you will navigate to this component using:

```
this.router.navigate([`products/product/${productId}`]);
```

Leave

```
<base href="/">
```

as is.

When you do this you will navigate to the correct URL from anywhere in your app.